# Mysql get closest numeric result comparing two columns (lat and long) at same time

Tags: mysql

I have a city with longitude and latitude, and a database of city names, also with longitude and latitude. Since there can be several cities with the same name, I want to match the one that is geographically closest.

To give an example, I have New York with a lat of 40.7262 and a long of -73.9796. I want to find the closest city of Bangor to NY, and there are several in the db:

```
Bangor  PA  40.86555560 -75.20694440
Bangor  NY  44.81222220 -74.39777780
Bangor  ME  44.80111110 -68.77833330
```

I can get the closest latitude with this query:

```
Select * from cities 
where city='bangor'  
order by abs(Latitude - 40.7262) limit 1;
```

and I can get the closest longitude with this query:

```
Select * from cities 
where city='bangor' 
order by abs(Longitude - -73.9796) limit 1;
```

but that does NOT get me the definitive closest city because Bangor NY wins in one case and Bangor PA wins another. How can I write my query to find the closest city taking into account BOTH lat and long?

Comment: Do you know Pythagoras Theorem?

Comment: So your basic distance formula is:  √((xA−xB)^2+(yA−yB)^2)  So, you need to make a temporary column computed from this formula, then sort by that.

Comment: @CaiusJard these are latitude and longitude values (degrees of angle), and not distance. Pythagoras theorement will not be an exact way to analyze the distance between two points

Comment: I'm sure it will be fine, but if you want to get into that level of navel fluff, try the haversine formula - https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @CaiusJard "I'm sure it will be fine". It's definitely not given the Bangor vs. NY sample. Even if 1 degree in lat and lng would always be the same or similar enough distance, this will ignore the fact that it's a globe, and to get from Banglor to NY you need to over the north pole and cross the date line.

Comment: If I flew from NY to PA the plane would go over the North Pole? Holy cow, I shoulda paid more attention in geography!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to determine the distance between two points on a map, given their latitudes and longitudes. You can get more details at this link: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

We determine the distance in km from the `Bangor` city, using the formula described in the referred link, and then `ORDER BY` on the calculated distance. `LIMIT 1` allows us to consider the closest city.

```
SELECT *, 
       111.045 *
       DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(40.7262))
         * COS(RADIANS(Latitude))
         * COS(RADIANS(-73.9796 - Longitude))
         + SIN(RADIANS(40.7262))
         * SIN(RADIANS(Latitude)))) AS distance_in_km
FROM cities 
WHERE city='bangor'  
ORDER BY distance_in_km LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: of course! I have even used this forumla before but for some reason I wasn't thinking clearly. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephen happy to help :)

Comment: just did that. :)